# is there a way to use matplotlib.patches.Wedge's radius in km instead of degrees?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I currently want to draw a sector-like wedge in Cartopy, so I look up the `matplotlib.patches.Wedge` method. It's almost the function I need, but the unit of the parameter `radius` it needs is in *degrees*, rather than *kilometers*.
Is there a way to use `matplotlib.patches.Wedge` method in *kilometers* rather than *degrees*?

Thanks.

[my idea image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvrjD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you saying "rather than degrees" means you're working with a position in lon/lat. The easiest way is going to be to convert your lon/lat center point to a location on the map. We'll also actually be using the radius in meters when plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.LambertConformal()
latlon_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
lat = 18
lon = 140
radius = 500  # In km
x, y = proj.transform_point(lon, lat, src_crs=latlon_proj)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
# Here we need to convert radius to meters
ax.add_patch(Wedge((x, y), r=radius * 1000, theta1=0, theta2=90))
ax.coastlines()
```